# find recurence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$a_n = n^4\,2^n$$

I need to find a recurence formula for this this sequence. Any ideas how to do this? Thanks in advance for any help! I've only solved this kind of problems for linear homogeneous recurrence relations, so I have no clue how to deal with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It rather depends what you mean. But if you want to recover a linear recurrence with constant coefficients (independent of $n$) here is a brute force way of working. It isn't elegant, and there are better ways, especially if you know what kind of answer to test.

Note that $$a_n-2a_{n-1} = 2^n (n^4-n^4+4n^3-6n^2+4n-1)=2^n(4n^3-6n^2+4n-1)$$

If we put $b_n=a_n-2a_{n-1}$ we have a cubic expression in $n$ to contend with, and the same power $2^n$.

The detailed calculations get complicated, but we can do without them, and concentrate on the form of the expression which involves $b_n=2^np_3(n)$ where $p_3(n)$ has degree 3. And we can do the same trick with $c_n=b_n-2b_{n-1}$ - check to see that the highest order term drops out so that $c_n=2^np_2(n)$ where $p_2(n)$ has degree 2.

We then proceed with $d_n=c_n-2c_{n-1}=2^np_1(n); e_n=d_n-2d_{n-1}=2^np_0$  ($p_0$ is constant) and finally $f_n=e_n-2e_{n-1}=0$

Then we work backwards:

$$0=e_n-2e_{n-1}=(d_n-2d_{n-1})-2(d_{n-1}-2d_{n-2})=d_n-4d_{n-1}+4d_{n-2}$$

As we follow through we see the coefficients in the pattern of $(x-2)^r$ ($e_n$ corresponds to $r=1$, $d_n$ to $r=2$ ... and finally $a_n$ to $r=5$). With a bit of work we can prove and generalise this result.

If I have my calculations right we get $$a_n-10a_{n-1}+40a_{n-2}-80a_{n-3}+80a_{n-4}-32a_{n-5}=0$$

Comment: Note that this argument goes through for $a_n=2^np_4(n)$ which satisfies the recurrence regardless of which polynomial of degree 4 we choose. 5 values are required to determine the coefficients - and likewise in the final recurrence, we need five values before we can determine the sixth.

Answer (score 4):

You have $a_n=n^4\cdot2^n$ and therefore $a_{n+1}=(n+1)^4\cdot2^{n+1}$. You want to express $a_{n+1}$ in terms of $a_n$, if possible, or at least in terms of $a_n,a_{n-1},\dots$ — however many previous terms are needed. In this case only $a_n$ is needed:

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)^4\cdot2^{n+1}}{n^4\cdot2^n}=2\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^4=2\left(1+\frac1n\right)^4\;,$$

so $a_{n+1}=\;$?

Comment: Brian - as a comment, this does not work for $n=0$. You need to give one value (e.g. $a_1=2$) to determine the sequence. This approach was the first thought I had, though.

Comment: @Mark: You’re right, of course, but even odds the sequence was intended to start with $a_1$ anyway. (I’m always mildly surprised at how many elementary treatments use $1$-based indexing.)

Answer (score 0):

Which kind of recurrence formulas are you looking for? The simplest candidate is is $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=2\frac{(n+1)^4}{n^4}$, or without $n$ appearing in the formula, $\sum_{i}\binom{5}{i} (-2)^{5-i}a_{n+i}=0$ (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation).